# Generic route for Web Api controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-routing

If request comes like

`mydomain.com/api/C1`

then I want controller `C1Api` to handle that.

I have tried route as below

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "{controller}Api", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

and type url as

```
mydomain.com/api/C1
```

but this is not working.

Do I need to make route for every api controller or I can handle it in generic way?

In short I don't want `Api` after controller in url.

Answer (score 0):

Since using convention based routing, the naming of controllers is important.

Change `C1Api` controller to follow the framework naming convention

```
public class C1Controller : ApiController {
    //...
}
```

And it should now match the default templates

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

for URL

```
mydomain.com/api/C1
```

Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. This would have been my first option if there wasn't other controller with the same name. Basically I want to add Web API in my MVC application and I already have controllers in there. I am appending Api to web api controller name to distinguish them

Comment: You should still be able to do Nkosi's suggestion. As you will be creating a folder called API and putting the API controllers in there.